# How to access global mixin in a nuxt plugin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt version: 2.14.12

Helpers mixins "@/mixins/helpers.js":

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    clickMe() {
      console.log('method fired')
    }
  }
}
```

Injecting mixins as plugin "~/plugins/mixins.js":

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import helpersMixin from '@/mixins/helpers'
Vue.mixin(helpersMixin)
```

Then including this plugin in nuxt.config.js:

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/mixins',
]
```

Then i can use a method `this.clickMe()` inside any Vue instance, but in a plugins i've inspected `context`, `context.app` - couldn't see info about mixin methods injected. Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution?